# I am trying to scrape data from a website using php and curl. Its source code has similar tags with same class

Tags: php, curl

This is the source code of the website`

```
<li>
  <div class="headingBox">Name of the Test: </div>
  <div class="detailBox">ALLERGY SCREEN</div>
</li>
<li style='display:block'>
  <div class="headingBox">Pre Test Information: </div>
  <div class="detailBox">No special preparation required.</div>
</li>
<li style='display:none'>
  <div class="headingBox">Home Collection Number:</div>
  <div class="detailBox"></div>
</li>`
```

When I write the PHP script below, I only get one value i.e. `Allergy      Screen`. How to get the data contained in all the div tags with  `class=detailbox`?

Please give a solution in CURL only.

```
<?php

function curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);    
$i=0;
$regex = '/<div class="detailBox">(.*?)<\/div>/';
if ( preg_match($regex, $data, $list) )
{
print_r($list);
}
 }
curl("https://www.lalpathlabs.com/pathology-test/allergy-screen-total-  ige-and-phadia-top");
?>
```

Comment: It's better to use Dom parser to do that

Comment: But if you want to use regex , change `preg_match` to `preg_match_all`

Comment: Thanks a lot,it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Don;t reinvent the wheel, use this

> http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Using this

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);

foreach($data->find('div[class=detailBox]') as $element) 
       echo $element->innertext. '<br>';
```

Done !

Comment: I am asking for a solution in CURL only. as i am told to do it in curl.